# ASP.NET Export Data To Word Template

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, xml, sql-server-2008, ms-word

I have several form letters in Word 2007 templates. I need to pass data from my web forms application(Sql Server 2008 backend).

I need to do this as seamlessly as possible so generating a text file for word to use as a datasource is not an option. I also want to avoid running Office on my web server for performance reasons.

I am wondering if there is a way to store the template xml in my database and populate the proper elements with my data when the letters need to be generated, and having this file downloaded directly to the users machine.

Does anyone have a solution for this type of issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you create a Word 2007 .docx file with tokens that you want to replace you can then easily replace the tokens on a server and send the client a new .docx file based on the old one with replaced tokens.

1. Create your template as a .docx file and save it on the server
2. Change all your mail-merge fields with easy to find and parse placeholders that are not going to appear int he document normally and will not require XML encoding. For example: {{FirstName}}.
3. Create a new blank .docx (zip) file for each document you want to generate
4. Read each file from inside the template .docx file
5. As you read the source file, search for and replace your tokens as appropriate
6. Be sure the XML Encode all text you put in the new document.  You can either use `HttpUtility.HtmlEncode`, an `XmlTextWriter` instance, or a custom method to replace the offending characters (<, ', ", >) with corresponding xml entities.
7. Send file to client

More complicated things could be done by manipulating the WordML tags but if you just want to replace some variable data, the above would be easiest/fasted method.

Comment: I've used this approach many times, the only thing you need to be careful of is loading characters/data that could break the XML document.  If your loading pure text you should be fine, but if you trying to load something fancy be careful!

Comment: sounds like a pretty nice solution. Have a link to any samples of how this might work? Im not familiar with working with text files in this manner or maybe I havent quite wrapped my head around this completely

Comment: @Zack, good point.  You can either use `HttpServerUtility.HtmlEncode` to encode the text, use an `XmlTextWriter`, or a custom method to replace the offending characters (`<`, `'`, `"`, `>`) with corresponding xml entities.

Comment: Are we talking about using the OpenXML sdk for word to generate the output document?

Comment: @stephen776, actually in this case, no.  This is simple string manipulation and can be accomplished by just unzipping the .docx file and manulpating the files inside as just text files.  That's easier than messing with the Office Open XML SDK which is not necessary in this particular case.

Comment: @Samuel Neff I see you mention more complicated operationg using WordML tags...In one of my cases I need to add a bulleted list of text...would this be possible using any of the methods you have suggested?

Comment: @stephen776, yes, if you want to add formatting within the variable content then you need to use WordML, and yes, using WordML you could do pretty much anything.

Comment: @Samuel Neff One more thing..I am having trouble saving the modified xml back into the package..I asked another question if you dont mind taking a quick look  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4793695/manipulating-word-2007-document-xml-in-c