# Manipulate word document in C# and ASP.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, ms-word

I want a way to manipulate a word document.
The document is a word template .DOTX file, and I need to hide and/or show specific paragraphs of the document based on conditions on my ASP.NET/C# application.

For example, if i entered the first and last names in my form, the generated word doc will show both fields, else of the last name is not entered it will not be shown in the generated document. I already know how to generate the doc but I dont know how to hide and/or show specific elements.

Comment: Take a look at: [What have you tried so far](http://mattgemmell.com/what-have-you-tried/)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Manipulating Word 2007 Document XML in C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4793695/manipulating-word-2007-document-xml-in-c-sharp)

Answer (score 0):

I am using Docentric Toolkit for this kind of scenario. The toolkit itself is using OpenXML in the background, so no Word installation is necessary. I suggest you take a look at the example for conditional content [here](http://www.docentric.com/documentation/examples/conditional-content).

In your ASP.NET application you prepare a data model. This model should also include a boolean field where you  set true/false value depending on whether you want to show conditional content in the document or not. The document template contains conditional tag, which is used as a placeholder for conditional content. Other tags (placeholders) can be nested in conditional content.